# Run a Ruby Script with Python

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby Script that when I run in the shell it works (as user):

`/home/user/wpscan/$ ruby ./wpscan.rb -u www.mysite.com`

However, I'd like to automate this with a function that I created with Python. Here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
wpscan_env = "/wpscan/"
os.chdir(os.environ['HOME'] + wpscan_env)
os.system("ruby ./wpscan.rb -u www.mysite.com")
```

Notice that the Python script is in a different folder, `home/user/python/first.py` and this is why I do the `os.chdir()` function. When I go back to the shell and type:

`/home/user/python/$ python first.py`

This is the output I get:

> Could not find addressable-2.4.0 in any of the sources
>
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and in order to get wpscan to work, it asked me to install Ruby 2.3.0. I did this via RVM.

`wpscan.rb` has a few dependencies and it seems it's not instantiating them. Also if I'm inside the wpscan folder and do `ruby ./wpscan.rb ...`  it will work. However if I try to do this from the home directory: `ruby wpscan/wpscan.rb ...`  it throws an error:

> [ERROR] cannot load such file --typhoeus
>
> [TIP] try to run 'gem install typhoeus' or 'gem install --user-install typhoeus'. If you still get an error, Please see README file or https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan

I have no knowledge of Ruby, this is my first real Python script, and I just installed wpscan 2 nights ago. I'm way out of my league here and I need help. Any further question can be elaborated per request.

Comment: try to run `bundle install`or something like `gem install addressable --version 2.4.0`

Comment: If I do that command in the shell, it works and doesn't show me this error though. Should I still try?

Comment: If you cannot run the Ruby command without Python either, e.g. get the same error, then this is hardly any Python question

Comment: No I think you misunderstood. `ruby ./wpscan.rb -u ...` WORKS in shell. But in Python it's outputting the error.

Comment: are you specifying ruby / gemset version on a per-directory basis? Make sure that you're not accidentally using different ruby versions (the gems need to be re-installed for each version). Maybe also try `sudo gem install` in case your root user has a different ruby version (which is common and expected).

Comment: In shell your `path` includes the path for Ruby stuff but your Python doesn't.

Comment: @Sevanteri I don't understand what your comment was but let me explain what the paths are: this Python script is in a /home/usr/python/first.py and the Ruby script is in /home/usr/wpscan/wpscan.rb. I told Python to go to that directory and to run the Ruby script, but it's not.

@maxpleaner I'm not sure what I'm doing! How can I find out? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and it had a different version of ruby. I had to install rvm to switch it to 2.3.0. Should I try `sudo gem install` in the shell or the script?

Comment: ***but it's not RUNNING the script*** it is, however entering the directory just fine.

Comment: I would really like to know ***WHY*** I got downvoted! I'm trying to be as precise as possible and willing to answer any question.

Comment: You should edit all this information in the question itself. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: Anyway, `rvm` is the reason here, within your script the command `ruby` does *not* point to the correct `ruby` as you set up by `rvm`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I have made the changes to the question. How do I go about pointing to the right ruby in my script?

Comment: I do not use `rvm`, probably an environment variable, or try `which ruby` in your shell where the command works, and use that command explicitly, e.g. `/home/usr/foo/bar/baz/ruby` in `os.system`. I only came to this question because it was tagged `python`.

Comment: `which ruby` gave me the output `/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby` and I changed the line to `os.system("/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby ./wpscan.rb -u www.mysite.com")` with no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably, `ruby` in your python script is not the same as `ruby` in your shell. This can happen if you e.g. have a default system ruby installed (e.g. from the system packages) and you install another ruby version via RVM.

When using shell, the RVM automatically loads it's environment from the shell init scripts (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) and knows which ruby to use from its settings. Whereas your python script does not load any rvm environment (it's not a login shell) and calls the default system ruby.

In that case, you need to explicitly call the correct ruby from the RVM in your python script. You can to it by calling the RVM wrapper:

- browse directories under `~/.rvm/wrappers/` and find the correct ruby version and gemset that you want to use
- in your python script, call the `ruby` command from this wrapper directory instead of the plain `ruby, something like:

```py
rvm_ruby = os.environ['HOME'] + "/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.0-p100@myproject/ruby"
os.system(rvm_ruby + " ./wpscan.rb -u www.mysite.com")
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried your answer and get a `sh: 1: /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.0@wpscan: Permission denied` error.

Comment: do you have the `ruby` at the end of the `rvm_ruby` string? i.e. are you perhaps trying to call the wrapper directory itself?

Comment: No I didn't! Thank you for the concise answer. I added `/ruby` onto the variable and it works like a charm! You just saved me hours of work!

Comment: @BlackBeltScripting then you might also consider accepting BoraMa's answer

Answer (score 2):

Thats so simple to execute ruby scripts from python...

```
import os
os.system('ruby filename.rb')
#if you want to store the output in seperate file
os.system('ruby filename.rb > outfilename.txt)
```